# Logging in microservices

Tags: logging, trace, microservices

assume we've got a number of Web API microservices, and they are written in different languages/framworks (some are ASP.NET Web API, some are NodeJS, some are Flask etc.).

I would like to log every request made to any service, and I would prefer a centralized log.

What method/tools should I use?

Regards,
Daníel

Answer (score 6):

There is a very famous approach called ELK:

- **Elasticsearch**: Search and analyse data in real time
- **Logstash**: Collect, parse and enrich data from each machine
- **Kibana**: Explore and visualise your data graphically

So all the information is collected by Logstash, stored in Elasticsearch and visualised using Kibana UI.

With this stack no matters who is generating the information (or what technology is using).

Comment: Thanks. Does Logstash handle collecting information from various sources, i.e. such as C# Web API, NodeJS etc.? (I think it does but I'm not sure). Also, would it be able to extract information such as what user performed the request, based on an access token (OAuth/OpenID Connect)?

Comment: Of course you do! It can ship logs from any source and parse them as you want. If the security token is stored in your logs, then it can extracts it, but if you want to translate the token into a real user, you'll need some logic to *enrich* the information prior to send them to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thats what I thought. It would be a classic JWT, so the logic would just have to know how to parse the JWT (and preferably verify that it is valid, i.e. to avoid logging requests as if they were coming from user A when in reality user B is trying to masquerade as user A by changing the corresponding claim in the token - which should fail when the token is validated).

Answer (score 1):

If your logs get bigger (like in the terabytes level) you will need a big data solution. I would suggest [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) with [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org/) and [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Periodically collect the newest log data and pump it into Elasticsearch, via a Flume agent feed into HDFS or [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/) with log data.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively you can use any language / logging work framework. All you need to do is to introduce one more service, the logging service to your family of services. All your services publish the logs to service bus which sequentially route the logs to the logging service for persistence.